# Azure Web App Config Not Taking Effect For A Long Time

Tags: azure, cors, azure-web-app-service

I am using two Azure Web Apps as a backend and a frontend for a bot (the details of the app don't matter for my problem). Anytime I would click a URL link from the frontend, it would fail with a CORS error. So I updated the CORS config to allow all domains with a '*'. This fixed my problem.

However, after thinking about it for awhile, I decided to try and restrict which domains it would allow. I replaced the '*' with what I thought was the incoming domain, but it was obviously the wrong one, because it was broken again.

So I replaced the specific domain with an '*' again. But I could no longer get the app to work. I restarted both the frontend and backend apps multiple times, but I could not get it working again.

I logged in again this morning, expecting to try to debug the issue, but now it was working! I made a similar change to the frontend with the CORS config, and it broke it again (not unexpectedly). But now we can't get it working again, even though we reverted to the config that was working before our change.

It seems as if it's not actually taking our configuration changes for a long time. Is it possible there is an older instance of the app running, and we're connecting to that older one? Almost like a blue/green deploy, where the route switch isn't being made right away. I realize that makes no sense, but it seems to be the only way to explain the behavior that we're seeing.

We verified it is not a problem with the browser possibly caching info, because two of us have tried it with two different browsers, and the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following on the Bot Profile page:

"Please allow 30 minutes for changes to bot settings to be reflected in all regions. Changes to icons may take up to 24 hours."

I think the configuration options fall under the same category as the options - it took 15 hours for our change to take effect.